# Parallelization of Combination

Tags: c, algorithm, mpi, openmp

I have got a piece of code that prints the combination of M number From N (nCm);

As it is a recursion, it works very slow when N is large.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N  80
#define M  4

int result[M]= {0}; // THE ARRAY THAT SAVE THE RESULT OF ONE COMBINATION
int queue[N] = {0};
int top = 0;

void comb(int* input,int s, int n, int m)
{
    if (s > n)
        return ; 

    if (top == m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            result[i] = queue[i];
            printf("%d\n", queue[i]);
        }
     }

     queue[top++] = input[s];
     comb(input,s+1, n, M);
     top--;
     comb(input,s+1, n, M);
}

int main()
{  
   int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
                  27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,
                  50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
                  73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80};

    printf("\ncombination():\n");
    comb(array,0, N, M);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I would like to know if there is any space for improvement in the algorithm above? 
if possible, can I use openMP ?

Thanks

Comment: The obvious improvement would be to get rid of the recursion. Doing so will give a huge boost in performance.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not a C programmer, but in most cases won't the C compiler optimize recursion to iteration anyway?

Comment: It used to be that compilers can only do that effectively when you have "tail recursion". Maybe compilers are smarter nowadays, but I wouldn't count on it. Disassemble the optimized code and see for yourself.

Comment: Btw this program crashes upon execution (stack overflow?). I'd start with weeding out the bugs before considering optimization.

Comment: on my computer under linux 16.04, the posted code seg faults after 4 combinations are printed.   So the code is not ready for optimization.  It is ready for some serious debugging.  I would advise against introducing 'openmp' until after the code works properly.   Right now, it seems to have some serious undefined behavior problems.

Comment: in general, variable names should indicate content or usage or both/  The posted variable names do not display any such information.  It is a very bad idea to have multiple entities those only difference is capitalization.

Comment: regarding optimizations.  the array `array[]` never changes. so would be better defined as 'const',  However, that is no actual need for that array as the statement: `queue[top++] = input[s];` will always place `s` into the `queue[]` array.   so the array `array[]` can be eliminated,.  This leads to the first parameter to `comb()` can be eliminated. and the statement: `queue[top++] = input[s];` replaced with: `queue[top++] = s;`

Comment: the biggest slow down in the code (not including the recursion) is the many callsl to `printf()`.   'N'+1 calls for each output line.   This could be easily reduced to a single call per output line by creating a format string once, then calling `sprintf()  to format all the values, once per line, then calling `puts()` to actually output the line.

Comment: regarding optimizations, the function: `comb()` has the parameter `n`, but that parameter is never changed.  so could eliminate that parameter and use the `#define` `N` within the function.

Comment: regarding optimizations, in the function: `comb()`, these two lines can be eliminated: `top--;
     comb(input,s+1, n, M);`

Comment: regarding optimizations: regarding these two lines: `result[i] = queue[i];
            printf("%d\n", queue[i]);`, the array `result[]` is only set, never read, so this line: `result[i] = queue[i];` can be removed.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("%d\n", queue[i]);`  This will print one number per line. so will take 4 lines to print one output.  Suggest remove the '\n' and only output a newline after all the numbers in a single combination are printed,  Suggest: `printf( "%d ", queue[i] );`  then follow the loop with: `puts("");` Note: `puts()` always prints a final '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

To me your code was even giving the desired output. [see](https://ideone.com/2mA8oe)

I have changed

1. printing format each combination was not good enough.
2. repeated combinations. (note: else part of if statement added).
3. reduced 2 recursive call with a loop and a recursive call. (Less space.)

The required code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N  20
#define M  6

int result[M]= {0}; // THE ARRAY THAT SAVE THE RESULT OF ONE COMBINATION
int queue[N] = {0};
int top = 0;

void comb(int* input,int s, int n, int m)
{
    if (s > n)
        return ; 

    if (top == m)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            result[i] = queue[i];
            printf("%d ", queue[i]);
        }
     }else{
         for(int ss=s;ss<n;ss++){
            queue[top++] = input[ss];
            comb(input,ss+1, n, m);
            top--;
         }
         //comb(input,s+1, n, m);   
     }
}

int main()
{  
   int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
                  27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,
                  50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
                  73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80};

    printf("\ncombinations():\n");
    comb(array,0, N, M);
    printf("\n");
}
```